# Rhododendron slowly dying of unknown disease

Tags: diseases, leaf

[image: Rhododendron leaf with disease]

Hello!
I'm from Germany and my parents Rhododendron plant is apparently dying. My mom is trying to figure out why.
It's planted outside, fairly large bush, fairly sunny space. When it was first planted (long, long time ago) it got like special Rhododendron dirt but that's probably long gone and mixed.

Anyone have any ideas what this could be and if this thing could be saved?

Thx!
Nik

PS: maybe one important note : we've had an extremely hot summer so maybe it is that?